# How to detect which TCP packets are part of a HTTP connection in C#?

Tags: c#, http, tcp

I am working on url tracker project where I have to track all sites visited by a user.
So I decided to do it by tracking TCP packets on every user request. So I am capturing all the TCP packets user requesting. But how can I figure out if it is a normal TCP request or HTTP request. Any suggestion will be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that running an HTTP proxy would be a better way of doing this. That way the browser (or anything else wanting to make HTTP requests) will know to use your application, and other applications won't be affected.

Comment: Actually I am developing a sniffer type project. So my application should be invisible.

Comment: @babaidebnath: In that case I would frankly rather not help you achieve your aim. Users should be aware if their communications are being monitored, even if this is forced upon them. Are you going to ask us how to write a botnet or a spam engine next?

Comment: Well for your information I am not doing anything that will harm. And there are many that kind of tools available in market. But want to make my own.

Comment: @babaidebnath: If it won't do any harm, you shouldn't mind telling users that your doing it, should you?

Comment: Nope, cause user is already knew which is me. As I told you I am doing it only for testing and nothing else.

Comment: @Babaidepnath: You may not intend harm, but someone reading the same answer might use it with *cruel intentions* (0:

Comment: @babaidebnath: Where did you say it was only for testing? You said you were developing a sniffer, and that it should be invisible. Why do you care about it being invisible if the only person it *would* be visible to already knows about it?

Comment: Well programming is the only thing where I find my happiness.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. Its been very helpful for me. By the way I found my answer in this site in another thread. Where those guyz knows the answer. and at least dont argue if they dont know the answer. The link is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529680/http-packet-reconstruction

Answer (score 0):

You would have to inspect the request for a HTTP message [such as `GET /images/logo.png HTTP/1.1`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message), and then you need to observe a response to make sure it actually succeeded.

Comment: But how to do that job ?