# Packet Logging with Pcap for C#

Tags: c#, logging, ip, pcap

I'm currently using the pcap library for C# and was wondering if there were any built in functions to remove the IP headers and the TCP/UDP/ECT headers? If not, could anyone post how they achieved removing such headers?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using [PacketXLib](http://www.beesync.com/packetx/index.html)? I've used this before and found it easy enough to code with.  Extracting the headers is simple enough by just knowing the basic fundamentals of the protocols

```
public const int ETHERNETLEN = 14;    // length of ethernet header
public const int IPLEN = 20;          // length of ip header
public const int TCPLEN = 20;         // length of tcp header
```

Assuming you're using the same library I did, you can then just bypass the headers to get to the raw data

```
int dataOffset = ETHERNETLEN + IPLEN + TCPLEN;
string rawData = "";
// Throw all the data into a string first up so we can work with it easier
for (int i = dataOffset; i < aPacket.DataSize; i++)
{
  byte nByte = (byte)aPacket.DataArray.GetValue(i);
  rawData += Convert.ToChar(nByte);
}
```

The code I'm looking at where I did this is probably nearly a year old though, so a bit hazy on what exactly I was doing.  I was doing some http-packet reconstruction as can be seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529680/http-packet-reconstruction) I posted.  Actually, looking at that thread, it was well over a year ago when I was doing this!

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of SharpPcap, a pcap wrapper/library for c#.

If you were using SharpPcap, SharpPcap breaks the packet down into datagrams. So you'd end up with an EthernetPacket that contained an IpPacket that contained say a UdpPacket. If you wanted just the udp packet you can easily extract that like:

```
Packet p = Packet.ParsePacket(rawCapture.LinkLayerType, rawCapture.Data);
var udpPacket = UdpPacket.GetEncapsulated(p);
if(udpPacket != null) { Console.WriteLine("found udp packet '{0}'", udpPacket); }
```

UdpPacket.GetEncapsulated() traverses the datagrams looking for the packet. Same kind of approach works for all of the types that are parsed.